# SensorStreamViewer, HoloLensForCV : "Failed to initialized media capture: Access is denied."

Tags: augmented-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I tried to get sensor stream from `HoloLens`, so I used the `HoloLensForCV`. 
(https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloLensForCV)

First, I checked that `SensorStreamViewer` project works, but few days later, I updated `HoloLens` and then it doesn't work. The error I receive is `Access is Denied`

[HoloLens Camera view capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNaLT.png)

[HoloLens Privacy Camera capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xQjo.png)

[The Webcam capability in VS capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd059.png)

And, I guess the error occurs in this part(SensorStreamViewer.xaml.cpp).

```
// Initialize MediaCapture with the specified group.
// This must occur on the UI thread because some device families
// (such as Xbox) will prompt the user to grant consent for the
// app to access cameras.
// This can raise an exception if the source no longer exists,
// or if the source could not be initialized.
return create_task(m_mediaCapture->InitializeAsync(settings))
    .then([this](task<void> initializeMediaCaptureTask)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the result of the initialization. This call will throw if initialization failed
        // This pattern is docuemnted at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997692.aspx
        initializeMediaCaptureTask.get();
        m_logger->Log("MediaCapture is successfully initialized in shared mode.");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception^ exception)
    {
        m_logger->Log("Failed to initialize media capture: " + exception->Message);
        return false;
    }
});
```

When I start others project like 'ComputeOnDevice', I can see an alert message window asking me allow to access camera. However, when I start 'SensorStreamViewer', I didn't see any alert message asking about camera access.

I started debugging, and confronted this error message.

> Exception thrown at 0x772C3332 in SensorStreamViewer.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::AccessDeniedException ^ at memory location 0x0180E680. HRESULT:0x80070005 Access is denied.
>   WinRT information: The required device capability has not been declared in the manifest.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide more details on your error message?

Comment: sure, The full message is "Failed to initialize media capture: Access is denied."

Comment: Did you enabled the WebCam capability, right?

Comment: Yes, I enabled the Webcam capability in 'Package.appxmanifect' file. Also, I checked the Camera Privacy in HoloLens Settings. I added some captured images.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. My HoloLens is running WIndows `17686.1003.x86fre.rs_prerelease.180603-1447
`. What's your version?

Answer (score 0):

In your Package.appxmanifest file, you need to add the following capability.

```
<rescap:Capability Name="perceptionSensorsExperimental" />
```